# Creating report based on input form in MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

I am currently developing a database to monitor my employees' work. Yet, MS Access is new to me and I encounter a fundamental problem when creating reports.

I wish the system can generate reports based on the values of an input form. Say, I would like to check Peter's work in January, I could simply enter:

```
   Name: Peter 
   Month: January
```

Then the Access would be able to generate a corresponding report. But I am not sure how it works. And I am thinking of three possible approaches.

(1) Input form -> Query -> Report

I look up youtube and learn how to build an Access form that passes a parameter value to a query. And then I can click the Create Report button.

(2) Input form -> Report
Not sure it works or not. But I learned a bit VBA which may be helpful in this case.

(3) Export to Excel
Export to Excel might be a good option. I can use various functions and filters to select the information I want.

Sorry that my question is being abstract. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pass filter criteria with OpenReport command. Build criteria referencing controls on form. Use concatenation or embedded parameters. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html.

Comment: I am using MS Access 2010. But I will check this out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways you could achieve this.
One way (it may be the most efficient or not depending on your query / data you need to output in the report).

Build the query.
Build a report with its record source based on the query.
Build a form with input controls and a button.
With the button you are going to open the report. In the open statement of the report you are going to specify the controls as filters to some of the fields retrieved by the query.
Example:

```
Private Sub POrdine_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_POrdine_Click

Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

stDocName = "EmployeeWork"
stLinkCriteria="EmployeeCode=" & Forms![frmNameOfForm]![cboEmployeeCode] & " AND WorkMonth=" & Forms![frmNameOfForm]![cboWorkMonth]
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_POrdine_Click:
Exit Sub
```

Am assuming the two comboboxes are going to pass a numerical value, the employee code (which would be a primary key) and the value of the month. Build the queries that feed these controls so that you may see the employee name and the month name. If in doubt just ask.

Notice how this approach may not work well for reports based on large amounts of data.